# Display reputation for low-rep candidate as "<1k"

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation, election, candidate-score

Reputation for [low-rep candidates to moderator](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/5#post-1059459) showed as it is [now](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6098/176217) (i.e. without suffix):

> [image: less 1k]

My request is to display reputation for such candidates as "<1k" for consistency with [high-rep](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/5#post-1067491) ones ">=20k":

> [image: more 20k]

There's no difference in candidate score for user with reputation below 1000 (score is still 0). Actual reputation could be made visible in tooltip if it's really needed of course.

Comment: Iam not sure, as for me it seem to follow privilege won, >10k, >20k, but under 1k I would like to know if its a 1 rep user versus one with >500 in example. Maybe a <100, <250, <500 & <1k if we follow the standard to display it

Comment: Not my downvote, but you know this was [recently changed](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6083/223536) (meaning it's unlikely that they'll change it again so soon)?

Comment: @Glorfindel it changed because of [bug report](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6083/176217) on ruSO. And then fixed, but [not too good](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6103/176217). My request about displaying rep as `<1k` was [posted in comment](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6103/6124#comment23514_6103) there and takes 5 upvotes, so I decided to post FR here on MSE.

Comment: Why?  Feature requests work better if they come with justification.  What problem are you trying to solve, what problems do you anticipate it could cause, and how would you mitigate those?

Comment: @Glorfindel, yes he knows. And me too. The problem was that "0k" looks like "OK", so it is confusing.

Comment: Don't see a pressing need for further complexity here.

Comment: @Shog9 I just want to see it more consistent. Also please have a look to another related [FR](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4069/176217) especially items 1 and 4.

Comment: The line thing is only gonna show up a year past the election, so not a big deal (if there's a shorter translation than размещено that would also resolve it).

Comment: @Shog9 what about colons?

Comment: That's a translation issue; there's a colon for each badge category in the English source, someone just dropped one when translating it.

Comment: @Shog9 no. I mean for "reputation" and for the "candidate score". There are no colons in English version too.

Comment: Ah. Meh. I guess that's something we could tidy up.

Comment: @Shog9 when do you plan to do something about it?

Answer (score 6):

I disagree with this. This lumps everyone under 1k together as if they're all equal. Yes, they may all effectively be getting the same bump to their candidate score but there is (generally) a big difference in participation between someone with 250 reputation and someone with 900 reputation. Lumping them all together seems unfair. On a site with lots of really high reputation users, someone with under 1000 reputation may have a non-existent chance of winning regardless of whether they have 250 or 900 reputation but this isn't *universally* the case.

The user's reputation isn't on the candidate posts anywhere else, so obscuring it like this hides what amount of participation they may have for some "prettying" of the candidate score box.

Having greater than 20K is generally considered irrelevant because once you hit that point, you're known to have a huge amount of participation and there's no change in your abilities to moderate the site. Additionally there's no real correlation between reputation and moderator ability, so the system has been set to cap the reputation bonus in the moderator score with the cap in privileges.

While someone with 150K reputation may have more subject matter expertise and more time spent on Stack Exchange, that doesn't *inherently* make them better at moderating the site over a 20K user... or even a 2K user. But we do use this for candidate score because they have *access* to moderation privileges that lower reputation users do not, which means they *may* have utilized them and be more familiar with how sites are moderated. There are certainly moderation privileges granted to users under 1000 rep, we should know which of them they have access to.

Comment: What about equality of the all with `>20k`?

Comment: Because above that level, you don't get any more moderation privileges. People tend to forget that reputation is not a measure of moderation capability.

Comment: If the difference between 250 and 900 is tangible, why candidate score is still 0 for them? Possible the current score calculation should be fixed to reflect that difference. But until it's not changed I don't see a reason to show 250 or 900 instead of the common `<1k`.

Comment: @Glorfindel, access to analytics is 25K, not 20K.

Comment: @Qwertiy that's true, but it's not a privilege required for day-to-day moderation tasks.

Answer (score -2):

That is a very common GUI design pattern:

`663` is fewer characters than `>= 20K` 
`663` is fewer characters than `< 1K`

Comment: ... but that doesn't make sense, either... 35,000 is equivalent in length to >= 20K... so how does that save any space?

Comment: @Catija OK it does not make sense to you.  It is a common design pattern.